# Sort by time in React Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How do I sort a column by time such as 5:30:05 AM, 1:20:32 PM, 5:22:10 PM in React Bootstrap Table Library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have fixed format of the time, try this

```js
const data = [
  {time: '1:20:32 PM', text: 'SOmehting' },
  {time: '5:30:05 AM', text: 'Hello World' },
  {time: '5:22:10 PM', text: 'blah blah' }
]

console.log(data.sort((a, b) =>
  moment(a.time, 'h:m:s a').unix() - 
    moment(b.time, 'h:m:s a').unix()
))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Vinson consider marking as answer & upvote if it helped

Comment: Thanks for an idea, Sorting is working now. I'm used this format
 moment(a, 'h:mm:ss a') -  moment(b, 'h:mm:ss a');